# How can I test an iPhone 3.0 device with Xcode 3.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I hope it's a simple one. I have a fresh install of Snow Leopard. I've installed the iPhone 3.1 SDK from the Apple Website, which includes Xcode 3.2. I all works fine, but in "Project > Set Active SDK" menu item, I can only find "iPhone Device 3.1" and "iPhone Simulator 3.1".

Now, I'd like to test my app with an iPhone 3.0. How can I make it? Can I download *just* the iPhone 3.0 SDK, without having to reinstall Xcode 3.1? I cannot find anything like this to download on the Dev Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install Xcode 3.2 on Snow Leopard, the installer gives you the option to install both the 3.0 and 3.1 SDK. Try launching the installer and installing just the missing 3.0 SDK. You should be able to do that without reinstalling the whole Xcode 3.2

Comment: Thanks.. I totally forgot that option :)

Answer (score 2):

Hold down option while clicking the top left bar. It brings up all installed SDK's

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project->Edit Project Settings. Under the General tab change the "Base SDK for All Configurations" to iPhone Device 3.0.  Now you can select iPhone OS 3.0 SDK's as well.